# Root permission freezes the android application

Tags: android, permissions, root

I have an application which tries to set system time/reboot, for which it requires root permission whenever I try to execute code which requires root, the system gives popup with "allow root access" and "cancel" buttons. Without allowing root access I can not move forward.
In my case this popup goes behind the application hence the app freezes.
If I terminate the application using IDE, I can see the popup there. If I click on allow permission and restart the application, the functionality to set time/reboot works well.

My question is,  is there a way to stop these request popups(as system is already rooted) or how can I bring these popups to front?

I am using Allwinner A31s android board

Answer (score 0):

I use this to ask for root permission and the popup appears in foreground:

```
public static Process requestPermission() {
    try {
        return Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("The phone needs root: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

ps: after the first acceptance it doesn't appear anymore even if i ask again. You can install SuperSu and grant automatically the permission to your specific app ;)